# When my variable has an apostophe in it, it cannot be used for onshow

Tags: php, tinybutstrong

I'm using a conditional in templating engine tinybutstrong to show a `<div>` when a variable is not blank.

```
<div class="notice">[onshow;block=div;when [var.notice;noerr]!=''][var.notice;noerr]</div>
```

It works well except for when the `$notice` variable has an apostrophe `'` in it. Otherwise the onshow conditonal doesn't run.

How do I fix this?

Comment: eww.. you may need to addslashes or htmlentities the variable first, sounds like a xss waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values may have quotes, you have to use delimiters and escaping :

```
<div class="notice">
   [onshow;block=div;when '[var.notice;strconv=esc;noerr]'!='']
   [var.notice;noerr]
</div>
```

The [manual](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_prm_when) has been updated in order to have this clearer.

But is you case, using a magnet seems smarter:

```
<div class="notice">
   [onshow.notice;noerr;magnet=div]
</div>
```